# Jquery Scroll Internal/External Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize for asking the wrong question. I found a post that is, however, asking exactly what I'm trying to figure out. I found this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785188/jquery-scrollto-internal-external-page.

Using the code below, I want to find out how to use a href="index.php/#home" to work on both internal and external pages. Another post shows this example, http://vostrel.cz/so/9652944/page.html, but it doesn't work on internal pages.

Javascript:

```
(function($) {
var jump=function(e)
{
    if (e){e.preventDefault();var target = $(this).attr("href");}
    else{var target = location.hash;}

    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top},1100,function(){location.hash = target;});
}

$('html, body').hide();

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);

    if (location.hash){
    setTimeout(function(){$('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();jump()},0);
    }
    else{$('html, body').show()}
});

})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href="index.php#home"]').on("click", jump);
```

If it's at the root of your site you could so something like:

```
$('a[href="/#home"]').on("click", jump);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      $('a[href^=#], a[href^="index.php#"]').bind("click", jump);
```

That would be the easy solution, if you want to match any page with a hash in it or have other restrictions post them and I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the [jQuery Attribute ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
$('a[href$="index.php#home"]').bind("click", jump);
```